# Intent filter is not working for calling screen

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent, intentfilter

I am designing a custom *calling screen* to show information, such as the caller's address book info, on screen during the phone conversation.
My app will begin when the user presses the call button by use of an `Intent Filter`, after which I will fetch other information from the address book and add it to the screen.

My problem is that when the call button is pressed, my `activity` is not launching. Is my *intent filter* right? Is it even possible to intercept the phone call `Intent`? Please share your knowledge on handling call event.

My `Intent Filter` is shown below.

```
<activity android:name=".MyCallingScreen">
  <intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case try to change your code following way:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

It's work for me if press on a call button.

Try to use following code to intercept the call:

```
<activity>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For HTC some changes there:

```
<activity>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Intent with action **android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED** is called when you making a call from phonebook by following way: Phone Book->Contact->Phone number Long Click -> Choose make call from dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to replace the call screen but it is relatively simple to intercept any outgoing call. You declare in your manifest a receiver:

```
        <receiver android:name="com.mystuff.CallInterceptor" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and you make a Java class for this interceptor:

```
public class CallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
        return;
        }
        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        //do stuff using the number
        //assuming you do nothing too bad the call will happen and the regular
        //call screen comes up - but you can bring up another activity on top of it
        //for example shwing address info
    }
}
```